# How to make this method generic for all passed Class types?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, reflection

I would like to make this method generic for all class types:

```
public static void printListSample(List<Class<?>> dateExtend) {
    System.out.println("dateExtend size: "+dateExtend.size());
    if(dateExtend.size() > 0){
        for(Class<?> mp : dateExtend){
            System.out.print("\n print entry - ");
            if(mp.getDate() != null){
                String dateDb = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy.").format(mp.getDate());
                System.out.print("value: "+dateDb);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Notice Class< ? >** - now like this it doesen't work; but I think I am on the right track.

I would like to dinamically cast Class passed in the parameter and then dinamically cast it for for-loop (so I don't have to do if (instance of SomeClass.. )

How to do this? I would need example code, really don't know how to write this.

**Edit:** 
getDate is method from my custom object I passed as param. So Java would need to figure out dynamically what class type was object that was passed.

I would like to write generic method for printing List (or ArrayList) of any passed type:

```
<MyClass> or <String> or <SomeOtherClass>,
```

so I wouldn't have to worry about types and casting would be done automatically.

**Edit (2): I would like to determine class type INSIDE method (I presume I can grab it from:**

```
<T> or <?>
```

**with class info I am sending) ?**

Comment: I think you should take a step back and explain what the original problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: No `Class` instance has a `getDate()` method on it. I suspect you need something like `List<? extends SomeClassWithAGetDateMethod>` as the parameter.

Comment: Yup. getDate is method from my custom class. I want that Java cast that dynamically, and don't want to write "extends SomeClassWithAGetDateMethod". I would like to java figure it out in method.

Comment: Why not? That's a sufficient way to do it. You don't need anything fancier: Java doesn't need to know the exact type, only that the instances have a `getDate()` method on them.

Comment: You could try sg like `<? extends Date>`. Unfortunatley, mp.getDate() will return an int, so the null check doesn't make sense anymore. So, can you add an example, which classes you expect to find in the list?

Comment: reflection. reflection everywhere.

Comment: Ock. How to reflect <?> type.. don't know how to do it. And then later pass that class object to cast

Comment: What would you want to do if you were able to get the class?

Comment: Andy, I would like to be able to print every List<String>, or List<MyClass> without modification

Comment: But you *can't* invoke the `getDate()` method on a `String`. You can't make it "that" generic.

Comment: Andy I would not invoke it, if it is not of class type String. That is why i think with reflection I need to get name of the passed object to determine of which class type it is. But I cannot determine if it is of type String If I'm not using reflection. I just don't know how to write it

Answer (score 4):

No `Class` instance has a `getDate()` method on it.

I suspect you need something like `List<? extends SomeClassWithAGetDateMethod>` as the parameter:

```
public static void printListSample(List<? extends SomeClassWithAGetDateMethod> dateExtend) {
    System.out.println("dateExtend size: "+dateExtend.size());
    if(dateExtend.size() > 0){
        for(SomeClassWithAGetDateMethod mp : dateExtend){
            if (mp.getDate() != null) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Incidentally, you don't need to check if a `List` is empty before iterating it: just iterate it, and if it has no elements, nothing in the loop is run.

```
if (list.size() > 0) { for (ElementType e : list) { ... } }
```

is equivalent to:

```
for (ElementType e : list) { ... }
```

(and also, `!list.isEmpty()` can be more efficient (and is no less efficient) than checking if the size is greater than zero).

Comment: Nope. I want to avioid "extends SomeClassWithAGetDateMethod". I want it to be fully generic in common sense, and let Java to determine class in method.

Comment: In what way do you consider this not "fully generic"?

Comment: In way Java could determine Class type with reflection or something else.

Comment: @DarioBB Java can't determine the type because of erasure. And you don't need to know anything more than "it implements this interface" if you only invoke the methods on that interface.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to invoke `mp.getDate()` I imagine that all the classes you want to accept in your list have this method;

If it's the case you can have a look at [Generic Methods and Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)

In order to have something like this :

```
public interface WithDate {
    public Date getDate();
}

public static void printListSample(List<? extends WithDate> dateExtend) {
    System.out.println("dateExtend size: "+dateExtend.size());
    if(dateExtend.size() > 0){
        for(WithDate mp : dateExtend){
            System.out.print("\n print entry - ");
            if(mp.getDate() != null){
                String dateDb = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy.").format(mp.getDate());
                System.out.print("value: "+dateDb);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Why is `WithDate` generic? Why then use a raw `WithDate`? Why do you need `T` over and above `WithDate`?

Comment: Can I do it to determine class type inside method from <T> or <?> ?

Comment: @Andy, thanks I forgot to remove it from the snippet copied the documentation

Comment: OK, 3rd question remains: why do you need `T` over and above `WithDate`?

Comment: @Andy yes you are right, if I loop on `for(WithDate mp` the `T` is never used again so I can make the same with a wildcard type.

Comment: Andy, because T is anonymous, and WithDate is specified name.. it is not "generic"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
   public static <T> void printListSample(List<T> dateExtend){
       ...
       if...
          for(T mp : dateExtend){
              ...
          }
   }
```

you will likely have the issue that the getDate() function is undefined for type T. There are a couple solutions to this.
1) you could cast mp (not usually considered a good meathod)
2) you could extend T in your input to only classes with a getDate function
3) you could use a try catch

```
   //option 2
   public static <T extends MyClass> void printListSample(List<T> dateExtend){

   }
```

"myClass" will need to be a parent class so that no matter what type T is in your list, it has inhered the function getDate();

Comment: Can instead of MyClass be wildcard? For example T or ?

Comment: no, it needs to be a class. but it could simply be object. everything extends object.